# LDAP: filter multiple UIDs

Tags: ldap, mediawiki

I am trying to set up mediawiki for a team and would like to LDAP authenticate only a set of users. I am aware I could come up with a group LDAP authentication.

But is there a shortcut to filter only a set of uids to authenticate.

Comment: Include usernames (or CNs) in the filter...? Anyway, strongly discouraged. At least create a group and only allow login to members of that group.

Answer (score 4):

The LDAP search filter you could use is:

```
(|(uid=a)(uid=b)(uid=c)(uid=...))
```

But as noted in the comments, a group is much easier and more maintainable. 
However if you cannot use a group, consider using an attribute of the users, like `description`, resulting in this filter:

```
(description=mediawiki)
```