# How to query multiple users from LDAP

Tags: java, unix, ldap

**How to query multiple users from LDAP.**

I am using 
DirContext.search(base,filter,scope); in my java program

as of now its working fine with one value filter. filter=("uid=name")

but my requirement is to pass multiple names to the filter at a time like

```
filter=("uid=name1,name2,name3....")  .
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ldap filter multiple UIDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486333/ldap-filter-multiple-uids)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

LDAP uses a "PREFIX" notation for its filters.

For example:

**OR** condition

```
(|(attr1=val1)(attr2=val2)(attr1=val2))
```

**AND** condition

```
(&(attr1=val1)(attr2=val2)(attr1=val2))
```

---

In your case, the filter criteria will be this:

```
filter = "(|(uid=name1)(uid=name2)(uid=name3))"
```

The above filter means:

> Find any user who has `uid=name1` OR `uid=name2` OR `uid=name3`.

This should list you users whose user IDs are name1, name2 or name3.

---

> **More Exmples:**
>
> Equality: `(attribute=abc)`     , e.g. (&(objectclass=user)(displayName=JohnDoe))
>
> Negation: `(!(attribute=abc))`     , e.g. (!objectClass=group)
>
> Presence: `(attribute=*)`        , e.g. (mailNickName=*)
>
> Absence:  `(!(attribute=*))`        , e.g. (!proxyAddresses=*)
>
> Greater than: `(attribute>=abc)`    , e.g. (storageQuota>=100000)
>
> Less than:    `(attribute<=abc)`    , e.g. (storageQuota<=100000)
>
> Proximity:    `(attribute~=abc)`    , e.g. (displayName~=JohnDoe)
>
> **(~= may not be compatible with all directory servers !!)*
>
> Wildcards:    e.g. (sn=J*) or (mail=*@example.com) or (givenName=*John*)

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a limit to how many ids that can be passed in? Would 2000 userids be unreasonable?